# Circular dependency in Django

Tags: django

I'm aware of similar question in SO, but none answer my question.

I've got the following models:

```
class Style(models.Model):      
    featured_item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

class Item(models.Model):      
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)
```

It's not a one to one relation, because several items can have the same style. However, one item can be featured_item of only one Style.

I could add a `is_featured_item` boolean field in my `Item` model, but that would make my admin more complicated.

Is there any way to solve this circular dependency?

Comment: I'd go with `is_featured_item`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the name of the model ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)), rather than the model object itself:

```
class Item(models.Model):      
    style = models.ForeignKey('app_name.Style')
```

Comment: This doesn't not answer the OP's question. And it's wrong. The circular dependency remains.

Comment: Well, probably, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: It does work. Thanks. I also added `related_name = '+'` to the `featured_item` field because I don't need the backwards relation.

Answer (score 1):

If in an `Item` can be `featured_item` of only one style, then this means that the `featured_item` must be unique across the `Style` table.

What about:

```
class Style(models.Model):      
    featured_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, unique = True)
```

Which is then equivalent to doing:

```
class Style(models.Model):      
    featured_item = models.OneToOneField('Item', related_name = 'featured_in') # Style -> Item relationshio

class Item(models.Model):      
    style = models.ForeignKey(' Style') # Items -> Style relationship
```

Which gives you a backwards relationship for each `Item` telling you in which `Style` it is featured, in addition to the forward relationship that tells you which style it belongs to.

I guess you will probably want to use a `limit_choices_to` clause so that an `Item` can only be featured in a `Style` it is part of.