# Django: getting rid of circular dependency

Tags: django, django-models

I have two apps, `commonapp` and `app1`.

Here's `commonapp/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
#from app1.models import SpecificFields

# Create your models here.
class CommonFields(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeFields(models.Model):
#    a = models.ForeignKey(SpecificFields)
    a = models.ForeignKey('app1.models.SpecificFields')
```

and here's `app1/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from commonapp.models import CommonFields

# Create your models here.
class SpecificFields(CommonFields):
    a2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I try to run the SQL from either `app1` or `commonapp`, I get the following error:

```
$ python manage.py sql commonapp
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
commonapp.somefields: 'a' has a relation with model app1.models.SpecificFields,
which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I realize this is an issue of a circular dependency.  Others have suggested of specifying the path to a class as a [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195715/circular-dependency-in-django) instead of the actual class, but that does not work.  I also cannot specify a string as the base class name in the derived class.

Is such a circular dependency possible without refactoring my models?

Comment: put SomeFields in app1/models.py

Comment: I don't want to do that.  I can put everything in one models.py, but I want to avoid doing that.  The project is being developed by different people, and each person is assigned an app.  Taking into account development organization and the logical app location for models, it makes things cleaner for the models to be in different apps.

Comment: The models I posted are generic names that I came up to reproduce the problem in a smaller scale and are not related to the project.  The project consists of multiple apps.

Comment: Ok, but with you restriction, the @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer you will survive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `app1.models` somewhere between `CommonFields` and `SomeFields`.

Comment: Wow, you've got to be kidding me.  I can't believe that worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2233706 you really should try to address the circular dependency though. If `common` is truly common, then it shouldn't take a dependency on something `specific`.

Comment: I understand.  The problem is that I have another app that depends on `common`, but not on `app1`.

Comment: I want to add that `common` depends on the other app, `app2`.