# Python package seems to be incorrectly imported as a module

Tags: python, django, models, python-import

I'm importing a package of mine called `shared` in a Django site. This package is an installed app, but when I'm trying to use it accessing its `models` module then the following exception is thrown:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'models'
```

I'm getting crazy with this! The rest of packages are imported in the same way and aren't causing any problems. This package has the `__init__.py`.

For example, in the simplest case it fails with the same error too:

```
import shared
print shared.models
```

If I use `from shared.models import Foo` it works, but I'm trying to do this to avoid circular dependencies.

Does anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: try `from shared import models` and then reference it as `models.Foo`

Comment: Will I have trouble if I import this module back from shared.models?

Comment: well .. it is a common issue. If you do run into issues, move the import from the top of the file to somewhere just before using it and you should be fine

Comment: I can't do this because there will be a collision with `from django.db import models`

Comment: I already knew that trick, the problem is that when working with PyDev if you use ^O to reorganize your imports, then they're automatically moved to the top. I'd like to understand this behaviour as I can't get it! :(

Comment: then do `from shared import models as shared_models`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376507/django-getting-rid-of-circular-dependency/17376563#17376563) for referencde

Comment: using `from shared import models as shared_models` works. So, why can't I just import `shared` and then do `shared.models`?

Comment: when you do `print shared.models`, it is looking for an attribute called `models` rather than modules. Here, only `shared` is imported and not the submodules of `shared`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `import shared` doesn't import child modules, but `from shared.models import FOO` does import all of the parent modules. You can import models in your __init__.py so that it comes in with `import shared` or you can specifically import shared.models after import shared.

```
shared/__init__.py:
    import models

import shared
print shared.models.FOO
```

or

```
import shared
import shared.models
print shared.models.FOO
```

Comment: Ah!! I didn't know this! And... If from `accounts.models` module I do an `import shared.models` and then from `shared.models` module I want to import back `accounts.models` module will I have a circular dependecie error using `import accounts.models`?

Comment: I'm not sure... in simple cases python will sort it all out but I don't know what would happen with django trickery in the mix.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I don't understand why in another different place I use this approach to solve a circular dependencie (importing the module and submodule) and there it works!

Comment: I think it will only work if the modules don't try to use each other during import. Later in functions would be okay. Basically, the  modules are only partially imported when they try to fiddle with each other.

Comment: Perhaps the stuff inside shared that uses accounts should be moved to its own module?

Comment: Hi! I've accepted your answer as it solves my initial question. However, regarding the issues we were commenting here I created another question that resumes the scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156500/experiment-trying-to-avoid-python-circular-dependencies

Comment: After further testing and ivestigation, I think that the statement "import shared doesn't import child modules" isn't fully true. If you read http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement you will see that you can import the package and then access submodules, etc. (Lazy import?) The problem here was that I was trying to solve a circular dependency and at top level I was accessing a variable from the other module and this is forbidden. A great discussion with @abarnert at the mentioned question above can give you a clue.