# Experiment trying to avoid Python circular dependencies

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I have a testing environment to try to understand how python circular dependencies can be avoided importing the modules with an `import x` statement, instead of using a `from x import y`:

```
test/
    __init__.py
        testing.py
    a/
        __init__.py
        m_a.py
    b/
        __init__.py
        m_b.py
```

The files have the following content:

**testing.py:**

```
from a.m_a import A
```

**m_a.py:**

```
import b.m_b
print b.m_b
class A:
    pass
```

**m_b.py:**

```
import a.m_a
print a.m_a
class B:
    pass
```

There is a situation which I can't understand:

If I remove the print statements from modules `m_a.py` and `m_b.py` or only from `m_b.py` this works OK, but if the print is present at `m_b.py`, then the following error is thrown:

```
File "testing.py", line 1, in <module>
  from a.m_a import A
File "/home/enric/test/a/m_a.py", line 1, in <module>
  import b.m_b
File "/home/enric/test/b/m_b.py", line 3, in <module>
  print a.m_a
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm_a'
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Side note: If you're intending to run this from the `test` directory as `python testing.py`, you should definitely not have an `__init__.py` file in the `test` directory. I don't think this is related to your problem, but it's still a bad idae.

Comment: Really? I didn't know this. What's the problem having `test` as a package? The same error happens under the same circumstances.

Comment: You should never run with a package, or any directory inside a package, as your PWD, or anywhere on `sys.path`. This is explained somewhere in the docs, but I don't remember where. Anyway, the big problem is that you can end up with two copies of the same module being available under two different names (so your globals aren't actually global, etc.). (There's also the fact that stuff may seem to work even though you've got it wrong.)

Comment: @abarnert - this is normal for packages that have multiple levels. The question about circular dependencies.

Comment: @Caumons, m_a hasn't returned from the `import b.m_b` statement and hasn't even created class A when m_b tries to use it.

Comment: @tdelaney: He hasn't tried to access `a.m_a.A` at all, just the module `a.m_a`; that's what he's asking about. (And it is _not_ normal to run with the middle of a multi-level package as your PWD.)

Comment: @abarnet - this came from a different question earlier today. maybe it could use some cleanup, but the question is about the circular dependencies.

Comment: @tdelaney: Which is why I posted the side note about running from the middle of a package as a side note in a comment, with the explicit statement that "I don't think this is related to your problem", while I posted the answer about circular dependencies as an answer, without even mentioning the side issue.

Comment: Of course this code makes no sense, it's just a testing code. I tried moving the prints at the end of both files and this still fails. I'm getting crazy with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only "works" with the print statements removed because you're not actually doing anything that depends on the imports. It's still a broken circular import.

Either run this in the debugger, or add a `print` statement after each line, and you'll see what happens:

- testing.py: `from a.m_a import A`
- a.m_a: `import b.m_b`
- b.m_b: `import a.m_a`
- b.m_b: `print a.m_a`

It's clearly trying to access `a.m_a` before the module finished importing. (In fact, you can see the rest of `a.m_a` on the stack in your backtrace.)

If you dump out `sys.modules` at this point, you'll find two partial modules named `a` and `a.m_a`, but if you `dir(a)`, there's no `m_a` there yet.

As far as I can tell, the fact that `m_a` doesn't get added to `a` until `m_a.py` finishes evaluating is not documented anywhere in the Python 2.7 documentation. (3.x has much a more complete specification of the import process—but it's also a very different import process.) So, you can't rely on this either failing *or* succeeding; either one is perfectly legal for an implementation. (But it happens to fail in at least CPython and PyPy…)

---

More generally, using `import foo` instead of `from foo import bar` doesn't magically solve all circular-import problems. It just solves one particular class of circular-import problems (or, rather, makes that class moot). (I realize there is some misleading text in [the FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) about this.)

---

There are various tricks to work around circular imports while still letting you have circular top-level dependencies. But really, it's almost always simpler to get rid of the circular top-level dependencies.

In this toy case, there's really no reason for `a.m_a` to depend on `b.m_b` at all. If you need some that prints out `a.m_a`, there are better ways to get it than from a completely independent package!

In real-life code, there probably is some stuff in `m_a` that `m_b` needs and vice-versa. But usually, you can separate it out into two levels: stuff in `m_a` that needs `m_b`, and stuff in `m_a` that's needed by `m_b`. So, just split it into two modules. It's really the same thing as the common fix for a bunch of modules that try to reach back up and `import main`: split a `utils` off `main`.

What if there really is something that `m_b` needs from `m_a`, that also needs `m_b`? Well, in that case, you may have to insert a level of indirection. For example, maybe you can pass the thing-from-`m_b` into the function/constructor/whatever from `m_a`, so it can access it as a local parameter value instead of as a global. (It's hard to be more specific without a more specific problem.)

If worst comes to worst, and you can't remove the import via indirection, you have to move the import out of the way. That may again mean doing an import inside a function call, etc. (as explained in the FAQ immediately after the paragraph that set you off), or just moving some code above the import, or all kinds of other possibilities. But consider these last-ditch solutions to something which just can't be designed cleanly, not a roadmap to follow for your designs.

Comment: I'm not an expert on how the import process works with Python and I read that importing the modules this way worked (in fact it seems that in some cases it does). So, what'd be your advice to solve the problem without having to move one of the imports at the end of the file? Is there a better option? Or am I doing something wrong with this approach?

Comment: There are various ways to solve this, all described in the same FAQ entry you probably read. Move one of the `import`s to the end; move one of them out of global scope; move the _access_ out of global scope; etc. But really, the best solution is to reorganize your code so you don't have circular top-level dependencies. I'll edit the answer to explain further.

Comment: OK, let's imagine module `m_a` depends on `m_b`, but `m_b` needs access to a class variable inside a class in `m_a`. This is my case and because I need to import the class to access it's variable member I'm getting the error.

Comment: If you try adding the line `A = a.m_a.A` at the end of `m_b.py` you'll get the error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'm_a'`

Comment: I think that the above error is because of the following (quoted from the FAQ link you included in your answer): "Circular imports are fine where both modules use the “import <module>” form of import. They fail when the 2nd module wants to grab a name out of the first (“from module import name”) and the import is at the top level. That’s because names in the 1st are not yet available, because the first module is busy importing the 2nd." In both scenarios I've shown: the second module is trying to access the first one while it's being loaded (trying to print it or accessing a contained class)

Comment: Now I think I've finally got it! And two more things: 1) When doing the `import x` to avoid a circular dependency you CAN'T use an alias for that import. 2) In my Django site, in the imports I don't include the parent package name (aka site name) just the app I want to import, so I can reuse apps in different sites more easily, I hope this won't cause me problems!

Comment: @Caumons: Obviously if you can't access `a.m_a`, you can't access `a.m_a.A`. If you can generate a [simple but complete and meaningful example](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates what you're trying to do, it will be a lot easier to provide suggestions for improvement than trying to keep things abstract. But anyway, from your other comments, I think you've got it. That's exactly the paragraph I think is misleading—it starts off saying that `import foo` is always fine, even though it ends up explaining why it _isn't_ always fine…

Comment: As for the Django question… I don't use Django, and I know there are various specific patterns common to Django that are very rare or even considered bad in the wider Python world, so take this with a huge grain of salt. But if you just make the apps completely independent top-level packages, then each site can just use whichever apps it needs, right?

Comment: I kept the examples abstract to do not complicate things but now I think I've got got it because now all different behaviours seem consistent to me. To sum up: if you use top level import statements in a circular dependency then you can't access the first module from the second at top level in any way.

Comment: As for Django apps... Yes, as they're python packages you can reuse them directly (unless there are dependencies). This is the reason I don't include the root (site) package in imports and it seems to work ok. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Caumons: That sounds like a good summary… It's not necessarily true for the top level of a package (notice that `a` is available when it's half-imported, even though `a.m_a` isn't… but notice that it's not very useful…), and it might be assuming some behavior that isn't guaranteed by Python 2.x and just happens to be true in CPython 2.7… but that's probably good enough. (If you want to _really_ understand the import system in depth, wait until you're ready to go to 3.x, where it's sensible and documented…)

Comment: I agree, accessing a hasn't any benefits here. I'm using CPython 2.7. Thanks, it's been a hard day, but I learned something new after all! :)

Comment: By Murphy's Law you can get away with the things that have no benefits but not with the things you actually want to do… More seriously, understanding what happens with circular dependencies, and when and why some things work, is very difficult, and it's usually easier to just focus on breaking the circle than trying to figure out what's happening…